# Is it common practice for customs agents to see travel funds before allowing me to board for trip to United States

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, proof-of-funds, malaysian-citizens

When leaving Malaysia for United States, is it necessary to pay customs agents for luggage for travel in Malaysian airport? Also is it necessary to show customs agent travel money?

Comment: [iATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/MY-Malaysia-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) says that there's a limit of MYR30000 or foreign currencies equivalent to USD10000 on export.

Comment: You mean to show you have enough funds for your trip? Or because you are carrying a suitcase full of US$100 bills/EUR 500 notes for some nefarious purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are no duty fees applied to checked baggage when departing Malaysia, assuming you are not exporting large amounts of commercial items, alcohol, tobacco, etc.  The only baggage fees would be those that the airline might impose.

You do not need to prove financial ability when departing Malaysia, the only country that would be concerned about your ability to support yourself while traveling would be the USA when you arrive.